# AttributeError: 'IntegerField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to constraint the input for salary in the forms from taking negative values, that's why I am avoiding to use Numberinput(), but using IntegerField() is giving me the following error

```
AttributeError: 'IntegerField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'
```

> Sharing Forms.py

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        exclude = ['created_at', 'updated_at']
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['salary'].validators.append(MinValueValidator(0))

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'gender' : forms.Select(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'dob': CustomDateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}, min_date='1964-01-31', max_date='2002-12-31'),
            'doj': CustomDateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}, min_date='1990-01-01', max_date = datetime.now().date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),
            'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'city': forms.Select(choices=CITY_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'state': forms.Select(choices=STATE_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'team': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'salary': forms.IntegerField(),
        }
```

I want Salary in the forms to only take integer values

Comment: an `IntegerField` is *not* a widget.

Comment: yes it should be a `TextInput` I guess or maybe there's a widget for that. If you don't want anything specific, just remove the line and keep the default django's widget for `IntegerField`

Answer (score 0):

An [**`IntegerField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield) is *not* a widget, it is a *form field*. The default widget of an `IntegerField` is a [**`NumberInput`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.NumberInput), you thus can use:

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        exclude = ['created_at', 'updated_at']

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['salary'].validators.append(MinValueValidator(0))

        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'gender': forms.Select(
                choices=GENDER_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}
            ),
            'dob': CustomDateInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control'},
                min_date='1964-01-31',
                max_date='2002-12-31',
            ),
            'doj': CustomDateInput(
                attrs={'class': 'form-control'},
                min_date='1990-01-01',
                max_date=datetime.now().date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
            ),
            'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'city': forms.Select(
                choices=CITY_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}
            ),
            'state': forms.Select(
                choices=STATE_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}
            ),
            'team': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'salary': forms.NumberInput(),
        }
```

---

> **Note**: Beware that the number input (`<input type="number">`) is often considered one of the worst ways to enter numbers with respect to user experience (UX). There was a [blog article on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/12/26/why-the-number-input-is-the-worst-input/) about this in 2022.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry. I am actually new to django. Hence, I done the mistake, I do want to use the integerfield() to set the attributes, min and max but i cant put directly inside the employeeform, because I want the meta data as well, or say label for the salary input field on the webpage, could you please help me with that?

Comment: @GaurishNinnekar: but we *are* using an `IntegerField`, the thing is not about not using an integer field, an `IntegerFIeld` is a *form field*, not a widget. A widget deals with how a form field is rendered on the webpage, so it is still an `IntegerField`, with a `NumberInput` as widget. Your other widgets like `dob` pretend to do some validation, but that is only at the client side: when a malicious request is made, the form will still validate it.

Comment: Alright. Understood it. Thank you so much for replying.